# Новый тэг для Jinja2

Tags: python, jinja2

Мне необходимо создать новый тэг для Jinja2, который бы оборачивал необходимые участки в одинаковый текст. На подобии вот такого:

```html
<ul>
{% wrapper %}
   <li>Word1</li>
   <li>Word2</li>
{% endwrapper %}
</ul>
```

После отрисовки получить вот такой результат:

```html
<ul>
   <a href="http://goo.gl"><li>Word1</li></a>
   <a href="http://goo.gl"><li>Word2</li></a>
</ul>
```

В [документации](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/extensions/#example-extension) написан пример, что необходимо сделать: мне необходимо создать новый класс, который опиывает поведение этого тэга. Я написал следующее:

```py
class WrapperTagExtension(Extension):
    tags = set(['wrapper'])

    def __init__(self, environment):
        super(WrapperTagExtension, self).__init__(environment)

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno
        body = parser.parse_statements(['name:endwrapper'], drop_needle=True)
        return nodes.CallBlock(
            self.call_method('_wraper', body),
            [],
            [],
            body
        ).set_lineno(lineno)

    def _wraper(self, body):
        return "<a href="http://goo.gl">{0}</a>".format(body)
```

Но во время исполнения я получаю следующую ошибку:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 489, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 449, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 486, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/project/sumsv/bgp_app/views/ripe_upload_views.py", line 258, in post
    tmp = jinja2.Template(obj.source)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 945, in __new__
    return env.from_string(source, template_class=cls)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 880, in from_string
    return cls.from_code(self, self.compile(source), globals, None)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 591, in compile
    self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
  File "/home/project/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<unknown>", line 2, in template
TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'wrapper'.
```

Как устранить ошибку и добиться желаемого?

Comment: У меня такое чувство, что это лучше делать не новым тегом, а фильтром

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас логическая ошибка: тегом `wrapper` вы оборачиваете два элемента `li`, но почему-то ждёте, что тегом `a` будет обёрнут каждый из них по отдельности. Чтобы такое работало, нужно парсить передаваемую в тег разметку, что не самая лучшая идея:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from jinja2 import contextfunction, Environment, nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension

class WrapperExt(Extension):
    tags = {'wrap'}

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = next(parser.stream).lineno
        body = parser.parse_statements(["name:endwrap"], drop_needle=True)
        return nodes.CallBlock(self.call_method("_process"), [], [], body, lineno=lineno)

    @contextfunction
    def _process(self, ctx, caller):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(caller(), 'html.parser')
        for item in soup.find_all('li', recursive=False):
            item.wrap(soup.new_tag('a', href="http://goo.gl"))
        return str(soup)
```

Во-вторых, судя по ошибке, вы не зарегистрировали расширение в шаблонизаторе:

```
env = Environment(extensions=[WrapperExt])
template = env.from_string('<ul>{% wrap %}<li>a</li><li>b</li>{% endwrap %}</ul>')
print(template.render())
```

> ```
> <ul><a href="http://goo.gl"><li>a</li></a><a href="http://goo.gl"><li>b</li></a></ul>
> ```

Comment: Реальная задача чуть сложнее, но я хотел понять принцип. Вы абсолютно правы по второму замечанию.

Comment: Благодарю! Ваш ответ очень помог! Всё получилось.

Comment: А не могли бы Вы пояснить смысл второй переменной в функции `_process(self, ctx, caller)`?

Comment: Это [контекст](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#the-context). В этом примере он не используется, но обычно полезен.